# Moving Ball java code isn't working

Tags: java, awt

I'm trying to write some code that causes a 2d ball to move around when the mouse gets near it, but it's not working. (I haven't been programming for very long..)
Here is the current code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;



@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MoveAway extends GraphicsProgram implements MouseMotionListener {

static int width;
static int height;
int x = 100;
int y = 100;
GOval runaway;


public void main(){
    System.out.println("Movement Detected");
    System.out.println("Stop Moving!");
    width = getSize().width;
    height = getSize().height;
    addMouseMotionListener(this);

}

public void run() {
    System.out.println(width);
    System.out.println(height);
    GOval runaway = new GOval(50, 50);
    runaway.setColor(Color.blue);
    runaway.setFilled(true);
    add(runaway);
    runaway.setLocation(x, y);

}
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("test");
    if(x - e.getX() > -50  && y - e.getY() > -50) {
        runaway.setLocation(x - 1, y - 1);
        y = y - 1;
        x = x - 1;
        System.out.println("Close!");
    }

    if(x - e.getX() < 50 && y - e.getY() < 50){
        runaway.setLocation(x + 1, y + 1);
        y = y +1;
        x = x - 1;
        System.out.println("Close!");
    } 
}
}
```

Some of this (or most) may be super-beginner stuff that's really obvious, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Dumping your code here and saying "It doesn't work" isn't what SO is for and unlikely to produce meaningful results; we're not here to debug your code for you. Please consider reading the [StackOverflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: What in particular is not working?  
  
What have you already tried?  
  
What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: One word.... Debugger. Learn to use it, locate you issue, then come and post a question pertaining to a known issue, only then will you receive help.

Comment: 1) A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough. 2) Don't expect much help with an obsolete API like ACM.  Better to use Swing from the start.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a lot going on that's not quite right, but I'll try to guide you on the right path.

- First of all, you need to do a little reading about [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). It's a design principle that separates the GUI from the logic, which will make your code more maintainable. You're going to need to make a different class to handle the MouseListener.
- This is apparently supposed to be your main class, so you need to make your main method have the following format

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  ```
- Some of your methods calls make no sense. For example, the lines:

  ```
  width = getSize().width;
  height = getSize().height;
  ```

getSize() is never defined in your program (though it should be. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html) on "getters and setters" for variables), and even if it were, what is ".width" and ".height" supposed to do? You need to re-think how you're setting those variables.

addMouseMotionListener() is also never defined, so trying to call it in the main method isn't going to do anything.

Your run() method is never called in main, so any code in there might as well not exist.

I'm also not sure what you're trying to do with mouseMoved(), which is also never called in your code, so I can't really help you with the logic there.

I hope this helps a little! Good luck. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to run your program through the main method.  Right now it seems like you have some methods that you aren't using at all (run)